# How to properly compile multiple files using GCC compiler and .o files with -o?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile multiple files using the GCC compiler through the command prompt.
I'm using this commands to compile them:
`gcc tokens.c main.c -c` to create the .o files; and using `gcc tokens.o main.o -o proyect.exe` to compile it (.exe file).The problem is, when I use the `-o proyect.exe` in the latter command, the program just doesn't work as is supposed to. When I only use `gcc tokens.o main.o` (without -o and naming it) creates the a.exe by default, and that exe works perfectly.
Is there a difference between using -o "name.exe" or just don't? I don't see a problem using -o and then naming my program, but it just freezes and exit when I use it. *I do not get any kind of errors/warnings when I use these commands*

Comment: What OS?  What distribution and version of gcc?

Comment: Can you please try to be more specific, *what* "just freezes and exit when [you] use it"? The linker? Your program?

Comment: And no there shouldn't be a difference between using the default executable name (`a.exe` when not using the `-o` option) and using the `-o` option to explicitly name your executable file. Well, no difference besides the file-name.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 Pro v2004 19041.207 and GCC 8.2.0.

Comment: When I say "just freezes and exit" I mean, after I type the *name*.exe to open it, it just opens for a second and then exits the program (returns to the cmd to type a new command). I know it should be not difference between just typing `gcc tokens.o main.o` and `gcc tokens.o main.o -o proyect.exe` but it happens what I said using the latter one